# Add click event to dynamic button inside calendar

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, event-handling, click

I have a calendar control in my website (vb.net in asp.net)(the standard calendar control but I manipulated it and now it looks like outlook calendar)

The events are added to the calendar as dynamic buttons, and each button has uniqe ID **which is the same even after postback.**

This is my code to generate the button and add it to the appropiate cell in calendar:

```
Protected Sub Calendar1_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs) Handles Calendar1.DayRender

Dim nextDate As DateTime
    If Not dsHearings Is Nothing Then
        For Each dr As DataRow In dsHearings.Tables(0).Rows
            nextDate = CType(dr(6), DateTime)
            If nextDate = e.Day.Date Then
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGoldenrodYellow
                Dim btn As New Button
                btn.Text = Left(dr(7).ToString, 5) & "-" & "جلسة في ملف" & dr(1) & " " & dr(2) & " (" & dr(8) & ")"
                btn.CssClass = "CalendarHearingEvent"
                btn.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                btn.ToolTip = "جلسة في ملف" & dr(1) & " " & dr(2) & " (" & dr(8) & ")"
                btn.ID = "btnHearings" & dr(9).ToString
                btn.UseSubmitBehavior = True
                AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Me.HearingButton_Click

                Dim lbl As New Label
                lbl.Text = "<br>"
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(lbl)
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(btn)

            End If
        Next
    End If
```

And this is the Handling sub:

```
Private Sub HearingButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

Everything is perfect, but the click event **not firing**

Please Help

Comment: I don't think you need the `Me`.

Comment: Please Any Ideas!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I used LinkButton, and have set href property of link button to

lnkButton.Attributes("href") = e.SelectUrl

Code

```
lnkButton = New LinkButton()
lnkButton.CommandArgument = objScheduleDetail.SelectedDate
lnkButton.Text = <Write your text here>
lnkButton.ID = "lnkView" ' you can make it unique as well
lnkButton.Attributes("href") = e.SelectUrl
e.Cell.Controls.Add(lnkButton)
```

Now when this link button is clicked Calendar.SelectionChanged event is fired. and I use Calendar1.SelectedDate to get the date of the clicked button.

```
Protected Sub Calendar1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Calendar1.SelectionChanged


   Calendar1.SelectedDate ' date which is clicked.

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [danish](/questions/tagged/danish) for your answer, but I need also to pass arguments. so I used your answer with extra code to meet the needs of my app.
The problem is that when a dynamic button inside calendar is clicked, it posts back the calendar event and not the button click event, so the app is not catching the button.
To bypass that, In my code behind I generated a linkbutton like this:

```
Dim btn As New LinkButton
btn.Text = "Text On LinkButton"
btn.CssClass = "CalendarEvent"
btn.ToolTip = "What ever"
btn.ID = "LinkButton1"
Dim str As String = "return EventonMyClientClick(" + dr(0).ToString + ");"
btn.OnClientClick = str
e.Cell.Controls.Add(btn)
```

This will generate a linkbutton inside calendar cell with OnClientClick pointing to a javascript function in HTML Code which goes like this:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" style="display:none;" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdEventSentId" runat="server" />
 <script>
    function EventonMyClientClick(val) {

        document.getElementById('<%=hdEventSentId.ClientID%>').value = val;
        var btn = document.getElementById('<%=LinkButton1.ClientID%>');
        btn.click();
    }

 </script>
```

As you see, The dynamic linkbutton passes my argument (dr(0).ToString) to [eventonmyclientclick](/questions/tagged/eventonmyclientclick) function. the function gets the argument, saves it in the hiddenfield and then perform a click event for the [linkbutton1](/questions/tagged/linkbutton1) linkbutton.
the page posts back and catches the [linkbutton1](/questions/tagged/linkbutton1) click event, which calls the code behind handler of the linkbutton that handles the argument saved in the hiddenfield:

```
Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim EventId As String = hdEventSentId.Value
        ....
        Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

I hope this will help others seeking for a solution for the same problem.